# Why does the rebol interpreter return different results?

Tags: rebol

Consider:

```
>> print max 5 6 7 8
6
== 8
```

The documentation states that `max` only takes two arguments, so I understand the first line.  But from the second line it looks like the interpreter is still able to find the max of an arbitrary number of args.

What's going on here?  What is the difference between the two results returned?  Is there a way to capture the second one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know Rebol but what I do notice is that you're using `print` inside of th REPL. The first output is from `print`, which is outputting the result of `max 5 6`. The second output is from the REPL, which is outputting the value of your whole expression — which is maybe just the last item in the list? If you changed the order of your inputs, I bet you would see a different result.

Comment: You're right.  It's interpreting it in a different order than I would have expected, which caused the confusion.

Comment: @hobbs has it, pretty much. The 'list' as he calls it, is not really a series! as far as the `do` dialect sees things, since they're not enclosed in square brackets, but are simply 4 integer!'s one after another. The first two serve as the args to `max`, while the last are just stand-alone integer! expressions that evaluate to themselves.

Comment: Well, if you type ">> 8" then you'll see "== 8" on console. That means "8, returned 8 back". In your example, you calculated something (max), then print out the result of the calculation (6) then you DO seven (7) and then DO eight which retuns 8 back to console (the == line means the return value, it is not an output of PRINT or PROBE)

Answer (score 2):

**max** is an abbreviation for **maximum**.  As @hobbs correctly guessed, it takes two arguments, and what you're seeing is just the evaluator's logic of turning the crank...and becoming equal to the last value in the expression.  In this case you're not using that result, so the interpreter shows it to you with "==".  But you could have assigned that whole expression to a variable (for instance).

What you were intending is something that gets the maximum value out of a series.  In the DO dialect all functions have fixed arity, and the right way to design such a beast would be to make it take *one* argument...the series.

Such a thing does exist, though there isn't an abbreviation...

```
>> print maximum-of [5 6 7 8]
8
```